# To which part of the sentence the "which"s refer?

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronouns

> Thus, in a last analysis it can be seen that ***the chief cause of the
>   downfall of the Sasanians*** was the material and spiritual bankruptcy
>   of the ruling class, ***which*** especially became apparent after the
>   bad government of Khusrau Parviz, and ***which*** must account for the
>   crumbling of so great ***a power*** before the attacks of a hungry
>   people newly arrived on the scene... [Read more](https://books.google.com/books?id=hvx9jq_2L3EC&pg=PA17&lpg=PA17&dq=must%20account%20for%20crumbling%20of%20so%20great%20a%20power&source=bl&ots=FcDPSWD7Dy&sig=-0zlXjs8NuIYpfyL6w_yl1MDCjg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1Te0VLylOon1UovygIAF&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

1. Do both "which"s refer to "the chief cause of the downfall of the Sasanians"?
2. Does "a power" mean "the Sasanians" in here? If not, what does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Both  instances of "which" refer to "the material and spiritual bankrupcy of the ruling class".
2. Yes, the "power" here means the Sasanians.

Comment: Stephoe was kind enough not to point out your misuse of "back", which should be "refer" (or if you insist, "refer back"— but "back" is not needed here because it is clear from context that you would not mean "refer forward".)

Comment: Thank you for the good point. I have just edited my post.